# .Net - How to process large no of MongoDB documents in parallel batches or in multiple instances

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to retrieve and process around 200k documents from a single collection everyday in batches (I tried loading everything in a list but that was a bad idea). All I need to do is get the documents, extract the records and store in a text file locally. I am trying this:

```
var options = new FindOptions
{                   
    BatchSize = mySize
};
using (var cursor = collection.Find(filter, 
       options).ToCursor())
{                   
    while (cursor.MoveNext())
    {
        var batch = cursor.Current.ToList();
        // my extraction logic
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me, I am trying to know how can I run the batches in multiple tasks or at instance level to improve performance. Also, are there better ways to load and process documents other than using cursor?

Comment: *" need to retrieve and process around 200k documents..."* - Process how? Rather than presuming you know how to best solve the problem, then perhaps you should show the actual problem you need to solve. I see no valid reason for your C# code to "process" such a large number of documents. What you probably instead want is the database to perform some type of "aggregation" which actually reduces down the overall set to a manageable size your application really needs. Likely far more productive than instructing how to spawn processes and pull parallel results out of a database.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, what I mean by "process" here is get the documents, extract each of the fields and add some zeros or space etc. For example, if one of my record field is "TransactionAmount" with the value  "50.00", I am doing something like 00000050.00 and writing to a text file, I am using string padding method for that. So, it is actually writing each of the fields in the document in a text file with some change in the format.